# Перенести файлы на виртуальную машину virtualbox, или подключение флешки

Tags: linux, virtualbox

Здравствуйте. Знаю что в интернете куча инфы но мне ничего не помогает. Виртуальная машина совсем не видет флешки, при создании общей папки она так же не появляется:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

потом набираю команду в виндовс на visualbox: 
net use x:\vboxsvr\\lol
открывается консоль буквально на 500 милисекунд и я даже не успаю посмотреть хорошо ли там все закончилось, ну после этого никакой папки не появляется в сети
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

внутри тоже полазил - ничего, а насчет usb ничего не понимаю. вставляю флешку linux её видит, а в настройках виртуальной машини её нету (скрин не могу сделать, так как блокируется почему-то если показывает окно что нету флешек)
В чём может быть проблема? Спасибо

Comment: папку нужно монтировать внутри VM.

Comment: как это сделать?

Comment: вы хотите папку в windows примонтировать в OS Linux, верно? чтобы файлы внды были видны в линухе

Comment: у вас же есть верхнее меню в нём пункт devices и так же в само низу эта же меню продублированно , но во время установки систему в VB надо заранее указать накопитель в соответствующем разделе , если что то не получается можно через тем вивер это попробовать сделать

Comment: Senior Pomidor нет, наоборот

Comment: ну по видео что я смотрел ничего не указывали, при установке я просто указал образ диска виндовса

Comment: @Horchynskyi а надо указывать

Comment: При установке виндовса, мне надо указать ту самую папку в линуксе, которая будет отображаться потом в виндовсе?

Comment: @Horchynskyi да